# найти слова в строке у которых кол-во букв = введенной величине regex

Tags: c#

Я написал такое решение, однако его проблема в том, что оно вырезает слово длинной n символов в любом слове, которое имеет больше чем n символов. Как сделать так, чтобы в MatchCollection попадали только те слова, у которых кол-во символов = n? n - это число которое вводиться в reg

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно воспользоваться указателями границ слова (word boundary) `\b`:

```
\b\w{...}\b
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло